# Error integrating "Microsoft App Center" with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, visual-studio-app-center

I am completely new to android studio and android development. I followed the instructions from the project page inside the app center. When I try to apply the first step:

Add the SDK to the project

In your app/build.gradle add the following lines:

```
dependencies {
    def appCenterSdkVersion = '4.1.0'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
}
```

I get the following error in android studio:

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:4.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I found this all depends on gradle and it's version but I couldn'd find a version that makes the error disappear

Current gradle versions

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that I did put the the dependendcies into the wrong build.gradle file (project instead of module). After moving the lines to the right file and forcing a gradle sync everything works.

Comment: hi @Weissvonnix does your analytics work on appcenter